# docusign integration with powerbuilder

Tags: authentication, powerbuilder, docusignapi

Has anyone done an integration with PowerBuilder Web Services? I followed the example in PowerBuilder examples library, which are all for http, whereas DocuSign uses https, and I think therein lies the problem with the PB example. I reviewed the "First Login" documentation, but it is difficult to bridge the gap to PowerBuilder.

1. I created a soapconnection object, called setbasicauthentication function, passing it "demo.docusign.net", my [Integrator Key]email address string in a string, and my password. This returned success.
2. I instantiated the service, which created an instance of the proxy. This succeeded.
3. I called px_Service.getAccountMembershipFeaturesList(accountid), passing my account ID. This throws an exception: "User_Authentication_Failed - Missing authentication header".

It could be that only a PowerBuilder developer would know what the problem is, but I thought I'd try here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Using PB Classic?  if so it doesn't support much past SOAP 1.1  You may be better off by creating a .Net class (using C#) to handle the actual communication with the WS and then expose methods via COM which can be called by PowerBuilder.  Instantiate the OLE object then use the ConnectToNewObject method to link to the .Net dll then call the appropriate methods you set up.

Using PB .Net? take a look at the help file for "Using .NET Web services with custom headers"

- Matt